# Jekyll не генерирует страницы из папки _posts

Tags: jekyll

У меня при сборке не генерируются страницы из папки _posts не из корня, не из вложенных папок. В чем может быть проблема??? При переименовании папки в posts генерация идёт но не как надо 
permalink: /:blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:slug.html

Файл оказывается в папке:
blog-> :categories и имя у него "yahr:month:day:slug.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что дело в дате. Она ещё не наступила. Я не знал этого свойства Jekyll и теперь понимаю как же он крут.